# Iterating over array and using splice() updates the parent array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

When a user clicks a button, I'm grabbing the `availableTags` array, storing it in a new `var tagsToWorkWith`. I then iterate over `tagsToWorkWith` and run `moveTag()` on each row in order to move every tag that was in `availableTags`.

Inside of `moveTag()`, I'm removing that row from `availableTags` using `splice()`. However, for some reason, this is removing the row from `tagsToWorkWith`, which causes my `for()` function to only run `moveTag()` on every other row.

**Why is `splice()` removing the row from `tagsToWorkWith`?** I'm explicitly setting tagsToWorkWith equal to the original `availableTags` to avoid this problem, but that doesn't seem to be working.

The below code runs with the error at http://jsfiddle.net/EdnxH/

```
var availableTags = [{"label":"Label A","value":"1"},{"label":"Label B","value":"2"}, {"label":"Label C","value":"3"}];

$(document).on('click', '#clickButton', function () {
    var tagsToWorkWith = availableTags;                         
    for(var countera=0; countera< tagsToWorkWith.length; countera++) {
        alert(tagsToWorkWith[countera].label);
        moveTag(tagsToWorkWith[countera].label, tagsToWorkWith[countera].value);
        //This should match the first alert label, since we haven't increased the counter yet. But, for some reason, moveTag()'s splice() removes the row from tagsToWorkWith.
        alert(tagsToWorkWith[countera].label);
    }   
});

function moveTag(itemToMove, itemToMoveValue) {
   var selectedTagArrayIndex = -1;    
   for(var counter=0; counter< availableTags.length; counter++) {
       if (availableTags[counter].value == itemToMoveValue) {
           selectedTagArrayIndex = counter;
       }
   } 
   if (selectedTagArrayIndex > -1)  {
       availableTags.splice(selectedTagArrayIndex, 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are objects, and objects are not "deep copied" when you assign references between variables. Thus, both your variables are referencing the exact same object.

Thus:

```
var a = ["hello", "world"];
var b = a;
a[2] = "again";
alert(b[2]); // "again" because "a" and "b" are the same object
```

If you want to make a copy of an array, you can use:

```
var b = a.slice(0);
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you for that note about the deep copying. Since I'm already loading the jQuery library, do you know if there is a major speed difference between `a.slice(0)` and `jQuery.extend(true, {}, a);` as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/761793

Comment: After reading through more of the answers at the referenced question, I see `slice(0)` does more of a soft clone, different then the function I referenced. I'll keep doing more reading and move on, thanks!

Comment: @John yes, it's a "shallow" copy. If the array has objects in it, then those objects are not deep-copied.